# Lyrics of The Dynamics' Please think it over

Tags: lyrics

I really do like this old song:
The Dynamics' Please think it over

I'd like to have the lyrics. I have searched the lyrics on the internet, but there is nothing. So I typed the lyrics by myself. **Could anyone help me check it?** Some lyrics I don't know what he was singing were marked as a question mark.

Can't you remember oh baby
Good time we had honey

Please think it over
Please think it over
Oh baby, oh baby

???
???

You are my sunshine
That warms me every day
Just think how I will feel oh baby
If you think of it
Don't you remember oh baby
The good time we had honey

I could be wrong baby
 I could be right
 Don't you feel the love is just burning oh baby
 Kiss each night

Comment: I've been reminded that posting the full lyrics to a song is likely to violate copyright law, so I've rewritten my answer to address only the corrections. I suggest you rewrite your question to include only the lines for which I've given corrections. Otherwise, there is the possibility of the question being deleted.

Comment: @Aaron Hello. Thanks for your suggestion. But if I delete some lines, it is hard to indicate which lines I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the line `the good time we had`, 'time' should be plural: `the good times we had`.
- The end of the chorus is `and hear my plea // Baby, hear my plea`.
- `If you think of it` should be `if you think of me`.
- `don't you feel the love is just burning` -- remove `is` (`don't you feel the love just burning`)
- `kiss each night` is `[unintelligible] kisses each night`.